# Liferay 7.1 - How to add a link html for a pdf file

Tags: java, html, liferay, liferay-7

I have a main module C-portlet that contains in the folder resources a pdf file.

```
resources/webapp/files/cg.pdf
```

I have a war theme. In one of its jsp page, i need to add a link for the cg.pdf.

For now, i have :

```
<a target="_blank" href="/o/Cportlet/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/webapp/files/cg.pdf"><liferay-ui:message key="cg-link"/></a>
```

but it doesn't work.

Last point, this pdf could be changed at anytime without a deploy again a module / war.

Is anyone have an idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your pdf file in one of your theme resource folders (for example the "templates" folder).

Now you can use `themeDisplay.getPathThemeTemplates() + "/cg.pdf"` or within your theme with freemarker `"${templates_folder}/cg.pdf"`

Comment: ok nice point.
But if my pdf file need to be changed or update, without redeploy my theme, do you have a solution ?

How can I open create my link with a pdf in the liferay folder for example ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this: imagining you cannot use the regular documents library... Or you module cannot use the library to get resources..

You could use a resource action if you have an MVC portlet. This would be the simplest way to just serve that resource, and you would only need to put the MVC resource command URL in you jsp. Regular portlets can also provide resources but not as easily.

For general modules you can create a struts action..which are normally way more complicated, especially if the resource is for private use only.